# Finding the right primary key

Tags: mysql, database, composite-key

I have decided to set combination of three values as a primary key(composite key) for my database table.Most of the times the first two columns will be unique.But in a few cases they are both same at which time the third columns value will be always unique for that row.The problem is that the third column is a description which is any string that the user can enter.I know it is not recommended to have a user given string as a primary key.But is it okay to have it as a part of the composite key.I really see no other option.

Comment: I'm assuming it is not possible to add a new column that could act as a surrogate primary key?

Comment: If not - perhaps using a timestamp as the third component is better than using the description

Comment: oh..timestamp could be good.I ll try and getback..thanks:)

Comment: Did using the timestamp work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible, you should add a surrogate primary key, meaning a key that is unique and has no business meaning whatsoever.

Composite primary keys very often turn out to be less 'stable' than anticipated - but if you MUST use one, using one or more component columns over which the user has little or no control (like created_timestamp) would be preferable.

Comment: to add to morsor´s answer: If you need the uniqueness of an primary key, you can create additional indices as "unique"

Answer (score 0):

Add a separate column called `id` and make it `auto increment` and use this column as a `primary key`.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Cheers.